# Universal Image Loader loads slower

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

I'm writing a custom gallery using UIL library and for testing the performance, I've modified `ImagePagerActivity`(of example code) to load images from sdcard. Everything works fine but loading is way too slow, sometimes it even takes 5 seconds to load a single image. However if I use in-built gallery, its way faster and loads more images in milliseconds. Here is the snippet of modified onCreate

```
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "dcim/100MEDIA/");
    File[] images = file.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File dir, String filename) {
            return filename.toLowerCase(Locale.US).endsWith(".jpg");
        }
    });
    String[] imageUrls = new String[images.length];
    for (int a = 0; a < imageUrls.length; a++)
        imageUrls[a] = "file://" + images[a].getAbsolutePath();

    options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.ic_empty)
            .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ic_error).resetViewBeforeLoading(true).cacheOnDisc(true)
            .cacheInMemory(true).imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY).bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
            .displayer(new FadeInBitmapDisplayer(300)).build();
    ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(this)
            .defaultDisplayImageOptions(options).discCacheExtraOptions(800, 800, CompressFormat.PNG, 0, null)
            .build();
    ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
```

and little modified ImagePagerAdapter

```
            @Override
            public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                 Toast.makeText(ImagePagerActivity.this, loadedImage.getWidth() + " x " + loadedImage.getHeight(),
                 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

Usually common image dimension is 2592x1552

UIL 1.8.6

Android version : 4.0.3

Others are just same as example code

Comment: Try to disable caching on disc.

Answer (score 0):

What does your ImageLoaderConfiguration look like?  What threadPriority do you set it?  Also, ImageScaleType.EXACTLY creates another bitmap so this will add load time.  For my ImageLoaderConfiguration I have threadPriority set to Thread.MAX_PRIORITY and threadPoolSize set to 5:

```
    ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(
            getApplicationContext()).threadPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY)
            .memoryCacheSize(memoryCacheSize)
            .memoryCache(new WeakMemoryCache())
            .denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory().threadPoolSize(5)
            .discCacheFileNameGenerator(new MyFileNameGenerator())
            .tasksProcessingOrder(QueueProcessingType.LIFO)// .enableLogging()
            .build();
```

Comment: ImageLoaderConfiguration is inside question's code. And I tried using your config with 20 MB memory cache size and its bit better. But still takes like 3 seconds.

Comment: Can you scale down the images and put them in the appropriate resource folders?